# How to extract body of for-loop?

Tags: c++, regex, string, grep

There are multiple C++ files. I need to extract the body of for-loop from these files.

Is there an easy way to do this maybe using grep. Consider there are no nested for loops.

Comment: Why would you need that?

Answer (score 5):

Without parsing the entire file, the answer is no.

for-loops are comprised of a [context-free grammar](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/summer2009/cmsc330/CMSC330_Context_Free_Grammars.pdf) and, as such, cannot be matched by a regular expression.

A more involved approach is to use `grep` to search for the beginning of a for-loop (`for` follow by optional whitespace followed by a lpar) then manually find the closing curly.

Unfortunately parsing C++ is Turing Complete, so unless there's some cute flag to pass to your compiler, you're hosed.

Comment: I think you mean np complete or hard and not turing complete.

Comment: @Otomo No, I mean [Turing Complete](http://blog.reverberate.org/2013/08/parsing-c-is-literally-undecidable.html), i.e., your parser must be Turing Complete to parse the source.

Comment: oh ... I forgot about templates. But searching for a for loop is in P, isn't it? Substring search is and parenthesis matching is too. Parsing != searching in a text file.

Comment: @Otomo Paren matching is inherently CFG, which is to what nested expressions reduces. Consider the basic (read not complete) partial grammar: `for(<bool-expr>) { <statement>* }`. No way to match closing curly because statements can also contain curlies. CFG cannot be matched by regular languages.

Comment: @Otomo _Parsing != searching..._ True, but when you _can't_ search (because regex won't work), your fallback measure is to parse. However, parsing is TC. Not good.

Comment: Yeah. That doesn't conflict with what I wrote. I agree that it's not possible to solve it with regex. But I think this has nothing to do with parsing the code.

Comment: @Otomo This has everything to do with parsing the code. Because there are defined grammar rules, parsing is the go-to. Parsing chunks the code. However, since the entire language isn't CFG, you can't use a parser (other than a TC one) to get those chunks. One of the chunks is the body of the for-loop. In the above grammar it would be `<statement>*`.